# replace \n with unicode to display new line in html correctly

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I have a multi-line string:

```
let str = 'line first \n     line-second-preceded-with-a-few-spaces';
```

I would like to inject it into HTML code. I managed to replace all spaces with `replace(/ /g, '\u00a0')` and I would like to do the same with `\n` but none of the Unicode values mentioned in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode) seem to work.

> The Unicode standard defines a number of characters that conforming
>   applications should recognize as line terminators:
>
> ```
> LF:    Line Feed, U+000A
> VT:    Vertical Tab, U+000B
> FF:    Form Feed, U+000C
> CR:    Carriage Return, U+000D
> CR+LF: CR (U+000D) followed by LF (U+000A)
> NEL:   Next Line, U+0085
> LS:    Line Separator, U+2028
> PS:    Paragraph Separator, U+2029
> ```

```
{str.replace(/ /g, '\u00a0').replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\u000a')}
```

What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: Just use CSS `white-space: pre-wrap`, none of this hacking around with unicode nonsense... Especially not when you're using **non-breaking space** which is not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 6):

You can replace `\n` with break line `<br/>` and then add as `innerHTML` like

```js
let str = 'line first \n     line-second-preceded-with-a-few-spaces';
str = str.replace(/ /g, '\u00a0');
str = str.split("\n").join("<br/>")
document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Or you use `replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");`. This would also do the same

```js
let str = 'line first \n     line-second-preceded-with-a-few-spaces';
str = str.replace(/ /g, '\u00a0').replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Or you can also wrap your string containing `\n` and `" "` in `pre` tag to treat them as new line characters and white spaces

```js
let str = 'line first \n     line-second-preceded-with-a-few-spaces';

document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = `<pre>${str}</pre>`;
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Note : The `pre` element should be used for text that has typographic formatting that affects the meaning of the content, such as in poems, ASCII art, transcripts, and, of course, computer code

Comment: Another option would be to replace the `\n`s with newline Unicode characters and place the whole text inside a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: But why <pre> tag changes the background color? o.O

Comment: _By default, browsers will display the content inside a pre element using a monospaced (or fixed-width) font such as Courier or Monaco_ [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/everything-need-know-html-pre-element/)

Comment: The `pre` element should be used for text that has typographic formatting that affects the meaning of the content, such as in poems, ASCII art, transcripts, and, of course, computer code.